# Kurento Java group call is not working when tried with docker image in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: javascript, webrtc, javabeans, kurento

**What I did I installed docker image using the following script:**

```
docker run --rm -i ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash <<'DOCKERCOMMANDS'

apt-get update
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes
gnupg

apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5AFA7A83

source /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release 2>/dev/null || source /etc/lsb-release

echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.13.2 $DISTRIB_CODENAME kms6"
>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list

apt-get update
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes
kurento-media-server

echo "Done! KMS version:"
kurento-media-server --version

DOCKERCOMMANDS
```

**Then I tried the following commands to run the group call**

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-group-call
git checkout 6.7.1
mvn compile exec:java
```

**After executing these commands, I got this result onto the terminal:**

> Kurento Java Tutorial - Group Call Version 6.7.1
>
> 2020-12-05 21:50:32.619 INFO 152397 --- [ main]
> o.k.tutorial.groupcall.GroupCallApp : Starting GroupCallApp on JUST-K
> with PID 152397
> (/home/kushpal/Desktop/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-group-call/target/classes
> started by kushpal in
> /home/kushpal/Desktop/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-group-call)
> 2020-12-05 21:50:32.625 INFO 152397 --- [ main]
> o.k.tutorial.groupcall.GroupCallApp : No active profile set, falling
> back to default profiles: default 2020-12-05 21:50:35.525 INFO 152397
> --- [rbeatExec-e1-t0] o.k.j.c.JsonRpcClientNettyWebSocket : [KurentoClient] Connecting native client 2020-12-05 21:50:35.528 INFO
> 152397 --- [rbeatExec-e1-t0] o.k.j.c.JsonRpcClientNettyWebSocket :
> [KurentoClient] Creating new NioEventLoopGroup 2020-12-05 21:50:36.018
> INFO 152397 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] o.k.j.c.JsonRpcClientNettyWebSocket
> : [KurentoClient] Inititating new Netty channel. Will create new
> handler too! 2020-12-05 21:50:41.660 INFO 152397 --- [ main]
> o.k.tutorial.groupcall.GroupCallApp : Started GroupCallApp in 9.714
> seconds (JVM running for 17.116)

When I hit localhost:8443 in chrome, I am getting this error: The page isn't working.

**Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!**

Comment: Please try to hit https://localhost:8443/